# Nuxt.js - Auto remove query of URL

Tags: nuxt.js

**Versions

nuxt: v2.13.0

node: v12.20.0**

I have a route like:

```
https://link-dev.com/abc/create?email=xx@gmail.com
```

When I enter this URL on Chrome it auto removes the query and turns it in to

```
https://link-dev.com/abc/create/
```

But it works fine locally.

Comment: What happens if you type`https://link-dev.com/abc/create/?email=xx@gmail.com`? (with the trailing slash)

Answer (score 1):

Only add slash before query

Replace this:

```
https://link-dev.com/abc/create?email=xx@gmail.com
```

With this:

```
https://link-dev.com/abc/create/?email=xx@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "preserveQuery: true" under "router" in nuxt.config.js file.

```
export default {
  // Other configuration options

  router: {
    // Preserve query parameters in the URL
    preserveQuery: true
  }
}
```